# WebStorm failing to recognise valid TypeScript destructuring

Tags: typescript, syntax, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm with TypeScript and hitting a snag when attempting to define a method's type using argument destructuring.

It is mentioned here (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5034) that in order to use type annotations with destructuring patterns, we must use the following pattern:

```
function someFunc(data: any) {
    const { x, y } : { x: number, y: number } = data;
}
```

This is applied to my TS file like so:

```
export default class foo {
    private bar: any;
    private myMethod: ({paramToUse}: {paramToUse: string}) => void;

    constructor() {
        console.log('hi');
        this.bar = "bar";
    };
}
```

In WebStorm I'm seeing a syntax error after `({paramToUse}):` stating ") expected" and it is causing syntax issues for the rest of the file to the point where it is unusable. This is not highlighted as a syntax error in VS Code or Sublime. Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

[image: syntax error highlighted in WebStorm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`({paramToUse}: {paramToUse: string}) => void` function type contains redundant information and doesn't make much sense, this is likely the reason why this syntax it isn't supported everywhere.

It doesn't matter here whether function parameters are destructured or not. Destructuring is specific to function implementation but not type:

```
private myMethod: (param: {paramToUse: string}) => void = ({paramToUse}) => {};
```

Comment: The example I've used could have been better. For instance, if I were to pass two properties in my object and I need to destructure them, the solution provided doesn't seem to solve that. The syntax that works in VS Code is as follows:

`public myMethod: ({paramToUse, secondParam}: {paramToUse: string, secondParam: string}) => void;`

Comment: Then the type is `public myMethod: (param: {paramToUse: string, secondParam: string}) => void;`. Again, what happens with `param` is specific to the implementation. This doesn't affect function type. You can destructure it as function param, or in function body, or not destructure at all.